# Mount Point Does Not Exist, Despite Creating It

Tags: linux, installation, partition, arch-linux, operating-system

I'm trying to install Arch on a Virtualbox VM. I'm following along [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrTRaT_bskQ). Not sure if relevant, but the VDI file is on an external hard drive.

I've created 3 partitions as per the video:

1. `/dev/sda1` **linux-swap** (~5 GB)
2. `/dev/sda2` **ext4** (~10 GB)
3. `/dev/sda3` **ext4** (~35 GB)

So early on, the video suggests running a few commands:

```
# mkdir /mnt/home
# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/home
```

But the last command gives me the following error:

```
mount: mount point /mnt/home does not exist
```

- **First question:** The Arch guide doesn't say I should partition my disk as the video does. Should I just forego the fancy partition
  scheme?
- **Second question:** If I should go with this partition scheme, how can I get around this error, and why is it happening in the first
  place?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this might not be the best forum. Is this better suited for superuser or unix SE sites?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because you created `/mnt/home` before mounting something to `/mnt`. When you did that, the "home" directory is hidden by the newly mounted /mnt filesystem.

You need to: (after unmounting everything above)

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mkdir /mnt/home
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/home
```

Comment: Nice. Love easy solutions. I'll give it a crack this afternoon

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how come the guy in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrTRaT_bskQ) video has no problems with doing things in the order I described in my original question?

Comment: If /mnt/home already existed on the mounted filesystem, he wouldn't have had a problem. Chances are he already made it in preparation for the video.

Comment: Nope, it's a blank drive, freshly partitioned :

Answer (score 0):

First you create a directory /mnt/home

```
# mkdir /mnt/home
```

But then you mount /dev/sda2 to mount, which shadows over /mnt/

```
# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Then try and map to a folder that does not exist as you never made the folder on sda2 which you mapped to /mnt/

```
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/home
```

Is this intended?

This would work

```
# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
# mkdir /mnt/home
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/home
```

because you mount sda2 to /mnt/ then create the folder on sda2 (Which is now /mnt/) then map /dev/sda3 to this folder (Which exists on /dev/sda2)

The real question is why do you want to map /dev/sda2 to /mnt/? /mnt/ is for mount points, sure you could store then on a different physical drive but it won;t really save space or anything.

Comment: This is how you install Arch, because you chroot to /mnt during the installation.

Comment: Ahh understood. I don't have any experience with arch so I'm use to using /mnt/chroot for that type of stuff. Good enough! Thanks for the information, appreciate it.